# SignalR 2.0.1, done trigger Ie8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, signalr

I'm using SignalR (2.0.0 then 2.0.1) to make some real-time web application. Every 5 seconds it receives some data... Also process user events. Anything works, but i have problems with IE8 (same with any version if IE + compatibility Mode).

```
var worker = $.connection.mainHub;
...
 worker.client.test= function () { ... };

 var connection = ((navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i) != null) ?
     $.connection.hub.start({ transport: ['webSockets', 'longPolling'] }) : 
     $.connection.hub.start())
 .done(function () { console.log($.connection.hub.id);});
```

1) The first one: after ~1-2minutes of working - everything became slower(user events like pressing buttons, simple css hover action, etc.), IE seems to be dieing. 
I thought the reason is memory leak.. it's a large amount of JavaScript (I'm using knockoutjs to build my html). But now i'm not sure

2) I need to have some clarity, how should I reload the page.
I'm using "location.href = location.href;" and everything fine, but in IE it seems to cause an error.
Not always, but often there is an error "$.connection.hub.id is undefined". I check $.connection.hub.transport, it's undefined too. Have no idea what i'm doing wrong...

Answer (score 0):

it seems there was redirecting to other page at the moment of 'done' occured. jquery.signalR stayed on the other page.. I guess there is some specific of brouser cash